# Mock unit testing for RxJava

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, android-testing

I'm writing unit tests base on Google's samples: [TaskDetailPresenterTest.kt#L102](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailPresenterTest.kt#L102)

They use `ArgumentCaptor<TasksDataSource.GetTaskCallback>` to trigger callback with fake data `COMPLETED_TASK`

```
@Test 
fun getCompletedTaskFromRepositoryAndLoadIntoView() {
    presenter = TaskDetailPresenter(COMPLETED_TASK.id, tasksRepository, taskDetailView)
    presenter.start()

    // Then task is loaded from model, callback is captured
    verify(tasksRepository).getTask(
                eq(COMPLETED_TASK.id), capture(taskCallbackCaptor))

    // When task is finally loaded
    taskCallbackCaptor.value.onTaskLoaded(COMPLETED_TASK) // Trigger callback
}
```

Everything work fine because they use `TasksDataSource.GetTaskCallback` to return data. See: [TaskDetailPresenter.kt#L36](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailPresenter.kt#L36):

```
fun getTask(taskId: String, callback: GetTaskCallback)
```

Then use as

```
tasksRepository.getTask(taskId, object : TasksDataSource.GetTaskCallback {
    override fun onTaskLoaded(task: Task) {
        showTask(task)
    }
}
```

---

But when I try to use **RxJava Single<> instead of normal callback**, like:

```
fun getTask(taskId: String): Single<Task>
```

Then use as

```
tasksRepository.getTask(taskId)
    .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<Task> {
        override fun onSuccess(task: Task) {
            showTask(task)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        }
    })
}
```

Then I **cannot** use `ArgumentCaptor<>` to trigger return fake data. It always throw `NullPointerException` when I execute my test, because  `tasksRepository.getTask(taskId)` is **always** return `null`.

So how can I achieve the same unit test like Google did, but in RxJava?

---

My unit test code:

```
@Mock private lateinit var tasksRepository: TasksRepository

@Captor private lateinit var taskCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<SingleObserver<Task>>

private lateinit var presenter: TaskDetailPresenter

@Before fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}

@Test 
fun getCompletedTaskFromRepositoryAndLoadIntoView() {
    presenter = TaskDetailPresenter(COMPLETED_TASK.id, tasksRepository, taskDetailView)
    presenter.start()

    // Then task is loaded from model, callback is captured
    verify(tasksRepository).getTask(
                eq(COMPLETED_TASK.id)).subscribe(taskCaptor.capture())

    // When task is finally loaded
    taskCaptor.value.onSuccess(COMPLETED_TASK) // Trigger callback
}
```

Note that all other parts (declare, setup, mocking,..) is the same as Google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already used this library but I would suggest you to use the Dagger 2 library with a MVP code architecture to ease your unit tests by improving your dependencies and couplings

Comment: I'm using Dagger2 in my other projects, but I think it didn't help anything in this case. Can you tell me how it help me in a more specific way?

Comment: well try to break the codes into small modules and methods in it by Dagger 2. Then call them with dummy data where the module will treat the call like a normal app call than test call.

Answer (score 0):

All this method is doing is showTask(task: Task). So assert that this method is called after your observer starts observing. You shouldn't care what the showTask is going to do once it's called. If you use Rx it is much better to make your methods take arguments and return value of the observe pattern to make it easier write unit test.

Comment: But you still need to check whether it showing the right `task` or not. May be it showing another `task`, then the test should FAILED.

Comment: You assert if it is the task you expected as such: assert(expectedTask, actualTask);

Comment: But the problem is, my test won't complete execution, it throws `NullPointerException` because `tasksRepository.getTask(taskId)`